# How can I top up the number of elements in a list to make it equal to ten?

Tags: c#

I have a City class and inside that a Detail class:

```
public class City {

        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public class Detail
        {
            public Detail()
            {
                ImageFile = String.Empty;
                Explanation = new HtmlText();
            }
            public string ImageFile { get; set; }
            public HtmlText Explanation { get; set; }
        }

}
```

In my code I have some lines that check how many details there are and if there are less than ten then I add new City.Details. I am using the code below to do this but it's located in a few different methods and does not look clean. Is there some way that I could simplify this and also add the logic of checking, counting and adding into my base City class?

```
foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, 10 - vm.Details.Count()))
            {
                vm.Details.Add(new City.Detail());
            }
```

Comment: Obviously you have a business logic rule that says "There should always be at least 10 details". You can implement this rule in a different manner. BTW, what is the type of  `vm` variable in the code example?

Comment: @RogerTaylor I assumed it was a City.  I would also like to know if "Details" is a List<Detail> or if there's actually a Details collection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said, use something like the following

```
 while(vm.Details.Count() < 10)
      vm.Details.Add(new City.Detail());
```

or even a regular for construct

```
 for(int x = vm.Details.Count(); x < 10; x++)
      vm.Details.Add(new City.Detail());
```

Otherwise when other people read your code  (or you look at it 3 months from now) the reaction is going to be "huh?" instead of just automatically recognizing what's happening.

Here are three ways to address the problem:

1) Just add ten Details to the City object when you create it, use those and then create more if/when necessary

2) Why do you need 10 Details if there aren't really 10 Details?  As much as possible it's best to have your objects truly represent what they are... representing.  So perhaps you are trying to fix what is just a symptom of a deeper problem.  But if that's not the case, then...

3) As the others have mentioned just move this logic into your base class.

Edit:  I should have also made clear on #3 that you need a way to make this process automatic so you don't have to explicitly call the procedure that pads it with extra Details.  I don't have enough info from your code to know how exactly to tell you to do this but if you want to provide more info as to why it's important to have 10 Details then I'm sure I could help further.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a MinReached and a FillDetails method to your City class.
The first one checks if you already reached the minimum, the second add new details up to ten.

```
public bool MinReached()
{
    return this.Details.Count >= 10;
}

public void FillDetails()
{
    for (int i = Details.Count; i <= 10; i++)
        this.Add(new City.Detail());
}
```

Comment: I would go as far as changing your `FillDetails` to an `IEnumerable<City.Details> GetFilledDetails()`.  This is probably should not be on the city class, as we don't know what type the variable `vm` is, but these functions should be on vm's type.

Comment: I supposed that Details was a property of City, but you're right, it's not stated anywhere

Answer (score 2):

If you always have the need to have to 10 Details to be made available can do something on these lines

```
Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => new City.Detail()).ToList();
```

This is for 10 Details exclusively or if you want to add the remainders then calculate the difference then use `.Concat()` to append it on to the existing list.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 - vm.Details.Count(); i++) vm.Details.Add(new City.Detail());
```

Comment: Yes that would be a lot cleaner and good point. Do you think I should add this into my base class. Also wondering if there is some way to do this using LINQ that would eliminate the need for the for loop altogether.

Comment: Anyway you'd better incapsulate this logic into some arbitrary class or into base class itself for cleaner design

Comment: I dont see a way of using LINQ here to improve performance. Good old for loop is the fastest of all

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type your cm variable is but if you want to add something to your City class you could add a static method to the City class named something like SetDetailSize that accepts a collection of Detail objects and a size you want to force the collection to be and then just call City.SetDetailSize method passing in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

"..do this using LINQ that would eliminate the need for the for loop altogether". 
Surely you could do it with linq but that does not mean the looping would not take place. Use ForEach linq operator. BUt this code is similar to what you had written except its in linq style

LINQ Code

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10-vm.Details.Count()).ToList().ForEach(counter=>vm.Details.Add(new City.Detail());
```

EDIT

Think this would solve your problem. As soon as your class instansiate , fill 10 cities by default. Use a counter for checking how many dummy elements are there in. Once user add a detail, replace the dummy with user's input. Put this in your base class and then you can forget about adding additional details at every other place

```
public class City 
{

   int counter = 0;
   public City()
   {
       //fill 10 elements by default
       Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(counter =>vm.Details.Add(new City.Detail());
   }
.
.
}

//Now define your add method as following
public void AddDetails(Details d)
{
   //remove the dummy element  
   vm.Details.RemoveAt(counter);
  //add original element and increase the counter, so next element would be added at next index
   vm.Details.insert(counter++, d);
}
```

Comment: With the solution the problem remains... the only difference is that here it's just 1 line of code to repeat all over the place instead of several.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create an extension method for the List collection.  This would allow you to call a method on a List of Detail objects from anywhere within your application.  Do the following:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
     public static void SetDetailSize(this List<City.Detail> details, int size)
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < size - details.Count; i++) 
             details.Add(new City.Detail());    
     }
}
```

This solves the duplication of code problem because anywhere you have a List of City.Detail objects, you can just make the following call.

```
vm.Details.SetDetailSize(10);
```

Make sure you have a using statement that references the namespace for the ExtensionMethods class.